# Download remote file from webserver in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have access to a playlist file (.m3u) with a link like `http://server.ext:port/page.php?username=test&password=pass`

When I paste this link into my address bar a download of a .m3u file starts and everything seems OK.

I want to filter and organize the contents of this file with my own PHP script.

My works on a local copy of the .m3u file is ok, but I want do this with a remote file instead.

I've tested with `file_get_contents` and `readfile` but i get the error message

> failed to open stream: Connection refused

I've tested with curl but I don't really know how to use it.

```
$url="http://server.ext:port/page.php?username=test&password=pass";
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET
CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

But impossible to connect to server .

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly simple with cURL:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://server.ext:port/page.php?username=test&password=pass';
$targetFile = fopen('download.m3u', 'w+');

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $targetFile);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

echo $result ? 'Download successful!' : 'Download failed: ' . curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Please also have a look at the available cURL options [in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php). Depending on the server setup and file size, it might be necessary to have additional options (e.g. max execution time, timeout time, follow symlinks, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for you're reply .

I've tested you're code but it's don't ok : download fail

Comment: Well, then there is most likely an issue with your link. I updated my answer so that it prints the error which occured, in case it failed.

Comment: this is the return : Failed to connect to (adress-server) : Connection refused . Access to a distant server is disabled by the operator who give me this download access ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the script is tested with the following file `http://www.ovh.net/files/1Mb.dat` and works as expected. So my best guess is that your link is broken, which should be easy to check if you download the file via a browser.

Comment: When i use the link in browser all is done, the file download since any problem . But when i tried to acces in serverside -> access is blocked .

Comment: Does the browser ask you for a username and password when you try to download the file? In other words, is there a pop-up window that prompts for credentials?

Comment: No, i think get.php in distant server, analyse all GET parameters in the link . and if all is ok, generate the content of the m3u file and force download it ...